# Will an exception while insert, rollback previosly inserted data?

Tags: sql-server-2008, insert, rollback

I am using SQL Server 2008.

I have an `INSERT` statement which inserts a huge number of records from one table to another.
While inserting, I got a primary key exception.

My question is...if the exception happens while inserting 5th row...Will all four records (which are inserted previously) be rolled back?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It will rollback all rows inserted *in that statement* unless you have the [`IGNORE_DUP_KEY`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2008/01/30/maintaining-unique-indexes-with-ignore-dup-key.aspx) option enabled on the index.

```
create table t1
(
col int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY=ON)
)

create table t2
(
col int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY=OFF)
)

INSERT INTO t1 values (1),(1)

INSERT INTO t2 values (1),(1)

SELECT * FROM t1 /*Returns 1 row*/

SELECT * FROM t2 /*Returns 0 rows*/
```

Comment: Another link to reference this SQLServer feature: [Create Index(TSQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx) viz setting IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON.

Comment: Do you mean ...Rightclick the Index..goto properties-> Options-> "Ignore Duplicate Values" check box? For me it's unchecked.

Comment: @Anish - If its unchecked then `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` is off then and all rows would get rolled back.